Странное переключение раскладки
Сделал тестовое переключение раскладки:
import win32api
import pyautogui
lcid = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()
lang_code = hex(lcid & 0xFFFF)
print(lang_code)
pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'alt')
lcid = win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()
lang_code = hex(lcid & 0xFFFF)
print(lang_code)

Но работает это очень странно: раскладка переключается, но Pyhton этого не замечает.
В print(lang_code) и до и после переключения он выводит одно и то же значение. При повторном запуске значение меняется, но всё равно остается одним и тем же, как до, так и после переключения.
В чём тут может быть дело?

Язык у вас переключается глобально, для всех окон сразу? Или для каждого окна в отдельности?

Если я правильно интерпретирую ответ на enSO, винда кривая и нельзя просто так взять и узнать изменившуюся раскладку

Но при последующем вызове скрипта он же правильно определяет раскладку. Вот в чем вопрос. Почему при первом проходе он ее не видит?

«при последующем вызове скрипта» — потому что винда передаёт информацию о раскладке свежезапущенному процессу, а старым процессам уже не передаёт

Да, по видимому так и есть. Спасибо! А можно как-то перезапустить процесс, что бы он получил свежее значение?

Возможно, логичнее адаптировать вышеупомянутый ответ на enSO под питон (но лично я ещё не умею)

Для меня это сложно. Думаю, придется создать отдельный Thread для получения информации о раскладке и каждый раз запускать его. Как вы считает?

Все эти ваши великоразумные программы рассыпятся в Windows 11, если пользователь будет достаточно умный чтоб полезть в настройки раскладки клавиатуры. Windows уже умеет удерживать несколько раскладок клавиатуры в мозгах - для каждого приложения своя. Гадать будете долго почему "не работает". Очередной код-велосипедик позавчерашанего дня. Если, не дай Боже, он окажется в каком-то серьёзном приложении, программист, который придёт на смену, выкинет как мусор в первые же пять минут этот никому не нужный код.

@FoxFox а ответ на данную тему тогда зачем публикуете, если он заведомо мусорный? Но самое смешное, что даже в своём ответе вы зачем то спрашиваете свою же программу какая у неё сейчас раскладка. При этом исходя из контекста вопроса и темы в целом, здесь речь идёт об автоматизации стороннего окна, а не своего приложения (глупо как-то самого себя автоматизировать, нет?). Следовательно велосипед не такой уж и велосипед и он не сломается даже если каждое окно будет сидеть на своей уникальной раскладке, ведь можно у конкретного окна узнать какая у него раскладка и при необходимости переключить.

Почитав тему из комментариев выше, пошёл изучать enSO и нашел интересное обсуждение.
Выводы:

Операционная система отправляет сообщение WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE
только в "верхнее активное окно", уведомляя его об изменениях языка.
Если приложение не активно, вызов метода GetKeyboardLayout всегда
будет возвращать последнее известное значение языка, которое может
быть устаревшим.

Собственно, решать проблему предлагают везде одинакова:

Извлечь язык клавиатуры, используя текущий активный оконный процесс.

Минимальный пример:
import time
import ctypes

def get_keyboard_layout():
    
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    # Дескриптор активного окна
    hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    # Идентификатор потока из дескриптора окна
    thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, None)
    # Идентификатор раскладки клавиатуры из thread_id
    layout_id = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
    # Язык клавиатуры из идентификатора раскладки клавиатуры
    lang_id = layout_id & 0xFFFF
    return "RU" if lang_id == 0x0419 else "EN"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        current_layout = get_keyboard_layout()
        print(f'Текущая раскладка клавиатуры: {current_layout}')
        time.sleep(1)


Немного позаимствовал идею с MessageBox и Language IDs сгруппировав это всё в один пример:
import time
import ctypes
import threading
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk

class KeyboardLayoutWatcher:
    languages = {'0x436' : "Afrikaans - South Africa", '0x041c' : "Albanian - Albania", '0x045e' : "Amharic - Ethiopia", '0x401' : "Arabic - Saudi Arabia",
                 '0x1401' : "Arabic - Algeria", '0x3c01' : "Arabic - Bahrain", '0x0c01' : "Arabic - Egypt", '0x801' : "Arabic - Iraq", '0x2c01' : "Arabic - Jordan",
                 '0x3401' : "Arabic - Kuwait", '0x3001' : "Arabic - Lebanon", '0x1001' : "Arabic - Libya", '0x1801' : "Arabic - Morocco", '0x2001' : "Arabic - Oman",
                 '0x4001' : "Arabic - Qatar", '0x2801' : "Arabic - Syria", '0x1c01' : "Arabic - Tunisia", '0x3801' : "Arabic - U.A.E.", '0x2401' : "Arabic - Yemen",
                 '0x042b' : "Armenian - Armenia", '0x044d' : "Assamese", '0x082c' : "Azeri (Cyrillic)", '0x042c' : "Azeri (Latin)", '0x042d' : "Basque",
                 '0x423' : "Belarusian", '0x445' : "Bengali (India)", '0x845' : "Bengali (Bangladesh)", '0x141A' : "Bosnian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)", '0x402' : "Bulgarian",
                 '0x455' : "Burmese", '0x403' : "Catalan", '0x045c' : "Cherokee - United States", '0x804' : "Chinese - People's Republic of China", 
                 '0x1004' : "Chinese - Singapore", '0x404' : "Chinese - Taiwan", '0x0c04' : "Chinese - Hong Kong SAR", '0x1404' : "Chinese - Macao SAR", '0x041a' : "Croatian",
                 '0x101a' : "Croatian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)", '0x405' : "Czech", '0x406' : "Danish", '0x465' : "Divehi", '0x413' : "Dutch - Netherlands", '0x813' : "Dutch - Belgium",
                 '0x466' : "Edo", '0x409' : "English - United States", '0x809' : "English - United Kingdom", '0x0c09' : "English - Australia", '0x2809' : "English - Belize",
                 '0x1009' : "English - Canada", '0x2409' : "English - Caribbean", '0x3c09' : "English - Hong Kong SAR", '0x4009' : "English - India", '0x3809' : "English - Indonesia",
                 '0x1809' : "English - Ireland", '0x2009' : "English - Jamaica", '0x4409' : "English - Malaysia", '0x1409' : "English - New Zealand", '0x3409' : "English - Philippines",
                 '0x4809' : "English - Singapore", '0x1c09' : "English - South Africa", '0x2c09' : "English - Trinidad", '0x3009' : "English - Zimbabwe", '0x425' : "Estonian",
                 '0x438' : "Faroese", '0x429' : "Farsi", '0x464' : "Filipino", '0x040b' : "Finnish", '0x040c' : "French - France", '0x080c' : "French - Belgium",
                 '0x2c0c' : "French - Cameroon", '0x0c0c' : "French - Canada", '0x240c' : "French - Democratic Rep. of Congo", '0x300c' : "French - Cote d'Ivoire",
                 '0x3c0c' : "French - Haiti", '0x140c' : "French - Luxembourg", '0x340c' : "French - Mali", '0x180c' : "French - Monaco", '0x380c' : "French - Morocco",
                 '0xe40c' : "French - North Africa", '0x200c' : "French - Reunion", '0x280c' : "French - Senegal", '0x100c' : "French - Switzerland", 
                 '0x1c0c' : "French - West Indies", '0x462' : "Frisian - Netherlands", '0x467' : "Fulfulde - Nigeria", '0x042f' : "FYRO Macedonian", '0x083c' : "Gaelic (Ireland)",
                 '0x043c' : "Gaelic (Scotland)", '0x456' : "Galician", '0x437' : "Georgian", '0x407' : "German - Germany", '0x0c07' : "German - Austria", '0x1407' : "German - Liechtenstein",
                 '0x1007' : "German - Luxembourg", '0x807' : "German - Switzerland", '0x408' : "Greek", '0x474' : "Guarani - Paraguay", '0x447' : "Gujarati", '0x468' : "Hausa - Nigeria",
                 '0x475' : "Hawaiian - United States", '0x040d' : "Hebrew", '0x439' : "Hindi", '0x040e' : "Hungarian", '0x469' : "Ibibio - Nigeria", '0x040f' : "Icelandic",
                 '0x470' : "Igbo - Nigeria", '0x421' : "Indonesian", '0x045d' : "Inuktitut", '0x410' : "Italian - Italy", '0x810' : "Italian - Switzerland", '0x411' : "Japanese",
                 '0x044b' : "Kannada", '0x471' : "Kanuri - Nigeria", '0x860' : "Kashmiri", '0x460' : "Kashmiri (Arabic)", '0x043f' : "Kazakh", '0x453' : "Khmer", '0x457' : "Konkani",
                 '0x412' : "Korean", '0x440' : "Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)", '0x454' : "Lao", '0x476' : "Latin", '0x426' : "Latvian", '0x427' : "Lithuanian", '0x043e' : "Malay - Malaysia",
                 '0x083e' : "Malay - Brunei Darussalam", '0x044c' : "Malayalam", '0x043a' : "Maltese", '0x458' : "Manipuri", '0x481' : "Maori - New Zealand", '0x044e' : "Marathi",
                 '0x450' : "Mongolian (Cyrillic)", '0x850' : "Mongolian (Mongolian)", '0x461' : "Nepali", '0x861' : "Nepali - India", '0x414' : "Norwegian (Bokmål)", 
                 '0x814' : "Norwegian (Nynorsk)", '0x448' : "Oriya", '0x472' : "Oromo", '0x479' : "Papiamentu", '0x463' : "Pashto", '0x415' : "Polish", '0x416' : "Portuguese - Brazil",
                 '0x816' : "Portuguese - Portugal", '0x446' : "Punjabi", '0x846' : "Punjabi (Pakistan)", '0x046B' : "Quecha - Bolivia", '0x086B' : "Quecha - Ecuador", 
                 '0x0C6B' : "Quecha - Peru", '0x417' : "Rhaeto-Romanic", '0x418' : "Romanian", '0x818' : "Romanian - Moldava", '0x419' : "Russian", '0x819' : "Russian - Moldava",
                 '0x043b' : "Sami (Lappish)", '0x044f' : "Sanskrit", '0x046c' : "Sepedi", '0x0c1a' : "Serbian (Cyrillic)", '0x081a' : "Serbian (Latin)", '0x459' : "Sindhi - India",
                 '0x859' : "Sindhi - Pakistan", '0x045b' : "Sinhalese - Sri Lanka", '0x041b' : "Slovak", '0x424' : "Slovenian", '0x477' : "Somali", '0x042e' : "Sorbian", 
                 '0x0c0a' : "Spanish - Spain (Modern Sort)", '0x040a' : "Spanish - Spain (Traditional Sort)", '0x2c0a' : "Spanish - Argentina", '0x400a' : "Spanish - Bolivia",
                 '0x340a' : "Spanish - Chile", '0x240a' : "Spanish - Colombia", '0x140a' : "Spanish - Costa Rica", '0x1c0a' : "Spanish - Dominican Republic", 
                 '0x300a' : "Spanish - Ecuador", '0x440a' : "Spanish - El Salvador", '0x100a' : "Spanish - Guatemala", '0x480a' : "Spanish - Honduras", '0xe40a' : "Spanish - Latin America",
                 '0x080a' : "Spanish - Mexico", '0x4c0a' : "Spanish - Nicaragua", '0x180a' : "Spanish - Panama", '0x3c0a' : "Spanish - Paraguay", '0x280a' : "Spanish - Peru",
                 '0x500a' : "Spanish - Puerto Rico", '0x540a' : "Spanish - United States", '0x380a' : "Spanish - Uruguay", '0x200a' : "Spanish - Venezuela", '0x430' : "Sutu",
                 '0x441' : "Swahili", '0x041d' : "Swedish", '0x081d' : "Swedish - Finland", '0x045a' : "Syriac", '0x428' : "Tajik", '0x045f' : "Tamazight (Arabic)", 
                 '0x085f' : "Tamazight (Latin)", '0x449' : "Tamil", '0x444' : "Tatar", '0x044a' : "Telugu", '0x041e' : "Thai", '0x851' : "Tibetan - Bhutan", 
                 '0x451' : "Tibetan - People's Republic of China", '0x873' : "Tigrigna - Eritrea", '0x473' : "Tigrigna - Ethiopia", '0x431' : "Tsonga", '0x432' : "Tswana",
                 '0x041f' : "Turkish", '0x442' : "Turkmen", '0x480' : "Uighur - China", '0x422' : "Ukrainian", '0x420' : "Urdu", '0x820' : "Urdu - India", '0x843' : "Uzbek (Cyrillic)",
                 '0x443' : "Uzbek (Latin)", '0x433' : "Venda", '0x042a' : "Vietnamese", '0x452' : "Welsh", '0x434' : "Xhosa", '0x478' : "Yi", '0x043d' : "Yiddish", '0x046a' : "Yoruba",
                 '0x435' : "Zulu", '0x04ff' : "HID (Human Interface Device)"
                 }

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_language = None
        self.root = Tk()  
        self.root.withdraw()  
        self.root.attributes('-topmost', True) # Поверх других окон для наглядности

    def get_keyboard_layout(self):
        user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
        hwnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, None)
        layout_id  = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
        lang_id = layout_id  & 0xFFFF # lang_id  = layout_id & (2 ** 16 - 1)
        language_id_hex = hex(lang_id) 

        if language_id_hex in self.languages.keys():
            return self.languages[language_id_hex]
        else:
            return str(language_id_hex)

    def handle_current_language(self):
        new_language = self.get_keyboard_layout()
        if self.current_language != new_language:
            self.current_language = new_language
            messagebox.showinfo("Изменение раскладки", f"Текущая раскладка клавиатуры: {self.current_language}")

    def watch_language(self):
        while True:
            self.handle_current_language()
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.watch_language, daemon=True).start()
        self.root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    watcher = KeyboardLayoutWatcher()
    watcher.start()


Немного разочаровывает, что в Windows нет АПИ для получения текущей раскладки(глобальной) и нужно колхозить через окно в фокусе. Но если немного разобраться, проблема становиться очевидной.

import time
import ctypes

def get_keyboard_layout():
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    layout_id = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(0)
    lang_id = layout_id & 0xFFFF
    return "RU" if lang_id == 0x0419 else "EN"
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        current_layout = get_keyboard_layout()
        print(f'Текущая раскладка клавиатуры: {current_layout}')
        time.sleep(1)

Может возникнуть вопрос: почему данный код при запуске в консольной программе всегда будет возвращать одну и туже раскладку(стартовую), даже если раскладку поменять?
Ответ: Проблема в том, что консольное приложение не позволяет обрабатывать сообщения Windows.
Так что придётся создавать своё окно и уже там обрабатывать сообщения  WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, которое срабатывает при изменении раскладки клавиатуры - по найденным материалам --один--, --два-- получился пример:
import ctypes
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

def get_keyboard_layout():
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    layout_id = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(0)
    lang_id = layout_id & 0xFFFF
    return "RU" if lang_id == 0x0419 else "EN"

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        wc.lpfnWndProc = self.wnd_proc  
        wc.lpszClassName = "MyWindowClass"
        wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        self.class_atom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(
            self.class_atom,
            "Current language",
            win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
            100, 100, 200, 100,  
            0, 0, wc.hInstance, None
        )
        
        self.h_textbox = win32gui.CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            "EDIT",
            "",
            win32con.WS_CHILD | win32con.WS_VISIBLE | win32con.WS_BORDER | win32con.ES_MULTILINE,
            10, 10, 150, 50,  
            self.hwnd,
            0,
            wc.hInstance,
            None
        )

        self.current_layout = get_keyboard_layout()  
        self.update_textbox()  

    def update_textbox(self):
        win32gui.SetWindowText(self.h_textbox, f"Язык ввода: {self.current_layout}")
        print(f"Язык ввода {self.current_layout}")

    def wnd_proc(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if msg == win32con.WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
            self.current_layout = get_keyboard_layout()
            self.update_textbox()  
        return win32gui.DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam)

    def run(self):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(self.hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOW)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        while True:
            win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyWindow()
    window.run()

Но опять таки, даже так раскладка будет изменятся только при фокусе (или возвращении фокуса) на нашем окне.

P.S. Возможно я что-то упустил или не правильно понял, не стесняйтесь поправить в комментариях и я дополню ответ.

Как определить текущую раскладку и если она неанглийская переключить на неё? Вот готовый консольный скрипт (для Windows; обращаю внимание, что после выхода из программы Windows вернёт назад ту раскладку, которая была в её среде):
import os
import ctypes
import keyboard

print("-" * 50 + "\nПереключение текущей раскладки клавиатуры на английскую:\n" + "-" * 50)

while ctypes.WinDLL("user32", use_last_error=True).GetKeyboardLayout(0) & 0xFFFF != 1033:
 keyboard.send("ctrl+shift") # или keyboard.send("alt+shift")

os.system("pause")


Забавно будет, если после смены раскладки попросить ваш код еще раз определить актуальную раскладку..

Эта функция устанавливает принудительно английскую. Хоть сто раз её запускайте, ей всё равно. Как я понимаю, автору непременно хочется использовать клавиатурные комбинации для работы с буфером в русской раскладке. А поскольку сделать это нельзя, он пытается принудительно переключиться на английскую. Вот именно это эта функция и делает. Если Вы заметили что-то существенное, так пишите по делу, а не неизвестно о чём и для кого.

Хорошо, напишу проще: вы запустили свой чудо код, он проверил раскладку, понял что она не английская и переключил её через кейборд. Проблемы возникнут 1) если вы опять решить проверить изменилась ли раскладка. 2) если вы ручками успеете сами переключить на английскую раскладку, то ваш код, когда запустит проверку вас приятно удивит переключив раскладку (достаточно добавить time.sleep(3) перед вашим кодом и сменить раскладку).

Вы читать скрипты вообще можете или нет?! Этот скрипт переключает на английскую независимо от текущего состояния!!! Если вы ручками..., если time.sleep(3)... - где это в моём коде?. Этот скрипт можно запустить автономно, а можно сделать из него функцию (взять две основные рабочие строки). Функция отработает и всё, без если бы да кабы. Именно это автору и надо.

Да, ваш код сработает, но ровно один раз. Повторный вызов(без перезапуска скрипта) уже выдаст не валидные данные.

Я ещё раз спрашиваю! Вы читать умеете?! Этот скрипт будет работать столько раз, сколько его вызовут! Где написано о неперезапуске скрипта? Что Вы мне тут всё время если ба да кабы суёте? Написано то, что написано и оно работает. Всегда. Без если бы да кабы. И функция из двух строчек будет работать. Она не  может не работать. Вызов, отработка, выход. Клавиатура станет английской! Вне зависимости от каких-то там никому не интересных проверок. Более там нет ничего.

Так вы сами протестируйте. Определите текущею раскладку, смените её и еще раз её определите.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
